# How to print the current user and system name in Unix?

Tags: c++, shell, unix

Please i am looking forward to learn how to print the current logged-in user and system name in Unix.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)   
{      
     //Print the current logged-in user / username.   
     //Print the name of the system / computer name.

     return 0;
}
```

I would be grateful if you can provide a line of code or two as demonstration. Thanks

Comment: Is this a home work question? You should probably do some research rather than ask something like this straight out. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(operating_system) for instance.

Comment: okay.. thanks. [between, it is not a homework].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getuid()` gets the id not the username. To get the username you'll have to additionally use `getpwuid()`:

```
struct passwd *passwd;
passwd = getpwuid ( getuid()); 

printf("The Login Name is %s ", passwd->pw_name);
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/96i6s)

And for getting the hostname you can use the `gethostname()` function.

Answer (score 5):

User --> `getuid()` (see also `geteuid()`).

Machine name --> `gethostname()`.

That is pure C. I don't know whether C++ has other library calls for that.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "pure C".  The functions are defined by POSIX, not by the C standard, and they might not be available on some systems (Windows, for example).  (Yes, I know the question is tagged "unix".)

Answer (score 4):

You need to call the [uname](http://linux.die.net/man/2/uname), [gethostname](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gethostname), [getuid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getuid) (and perhaps [getgid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getgid)) [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_calls), and to convert the numerical uid with [getpwent](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwent) function.