# Find out current user and create a text file on the desktop in C++

Tags: c++, windows

How can I find out the currently logged on user then create a text file on the desktop of that user? I have been researching for hours, trying different code and I am still unable to do this.

Thanks!
Drew

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863337/programmatically-find-username-in-c or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723956/how-to-print-the-current-user-and-system-name-in-unix.. this may help

Comment: What is the target operating system?

Comment: -1, missing information, What Have You Tried, see other comments

Comment: @Skyler -  Windows
DILi - Everything I have found on Google. So much I don't remember it all. I have spent a long time on this and I am sorry if you feel the need to post comments like that when I have explained what I want.

Comment: Also, all of the previous links I have tired, I can print with wcout the Username but I am not trying to do that; I am trying to createwrite to a text file on their desktop. I have been unsuccessful in being able to modify the cout code to write said file.

Comment: By the way, I have had the closest success with CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY. I am just having trouble now with writing a file to the desktop of the String Buffer that holds the user name.

Comment: `TCHAR strPath[ MAX_PATH ];
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(
    0,
    strPath,
    CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY,
    FALSE );

ofstream myfile; 
 myfile.open (strPath"\\Desktop\\text.txt");`

Jesus why can't this site just use [code] & [/code]. So much easier.
Essentially this plus the file write... http://weseetips.com/2008/05/01/how-to-get-the-path-of-special-folders-in-windows/

Comment: Because there are a million ways of doing this. And because if we see your mistake we might be able to show you how not to make the mistake again. We are not a source of code but help people who have already tried and failed and have code to prove that.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ that is not the way to concatenate strings. try:

```
myfile.open (string(strPath) + "\\text.txt");
```

In C++ you cannot concatenate strings by just writing them next to each other. One of the ways is to strcat them or use the idiomatic c++ approach of converting to `std::string` and then use the `+` to concatenate them.

Comment: Thank you, that got me further than I have been but now I am receiving the compile error:

"error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'TCHAR [260]' to 'std::string'
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous"

Comment: `TCHARS` are defines to either `char` or `wchar_t` depending on wether UNICODE OR MBCS is defined or not. Are you planning on using your software on non-ascii countries? If no then disable wide strings and use `char` with the corresponding `SHGetSpecialFolderPathA` version of the function. Else you will have to convert your `wchar_t` array to a `char` array with `widechartomultibyte` function before you can create the `std::string`. Or use the corresponding `_tcscat` functions for c string manipulations provided by MS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1x0y282%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I am sorry, it's late and I am a little confused. I have modified the code and removed the 'TCHAR' to 'CHAR' and changed 'SHGetSpecialFolderPath(' to 'SHGetSpecialFolderPathA('. I am now looking in the properties for the project under the character set and am sure of which to set (Unicode or MBCS). It seems which I set still yields compile errors.

Again, sorry I am quite tired.